# Convergence in $L^p$ spaces.

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-integral, lp-spaces

Prove that for all integrable functions $g_n, g$, we have the implication $\|g_n-g\|_1\to 0\Rightarrow \|g_n\|_1\to \|g\|_1$ as $n\to \infty$. Is the converse true?

It seems like $|g_n-g|_1 \to 0$ implies that $|\int_X g_n dm - \int_x g dm| \to 0$, since the latter is bounded by $\int_X|g_n-g| dm$. Is it okay to just take the limit and call it good? I feel like I am missing some details here. Also, what about the converse?

Comment: That would  give a valid proof only for the case where the $g_n$ and $g$ were nonnegative.

Answer (score 2):

$(\Rightarrow)$ By the reverse triangle inequality 
$$
| \|g_n\| -\|g\| | \leq \| g_n -g \| 
$$
Since $\| g_n -g \| \to 0$ then clearly  $\|g_n\| \to \|g\|$

> The converse is also true as long $g, g_n \in L ^1$ and $g_n \to g$ a.e. In that case you can use the next argument:

$(\Leftarrow)$ First note that since $|g_n -g| \leq |g_n| + |g|$ then $|g_n -g| \in L^1$. Also $ |g_n| + |g| \to 2|g|$ a.e and by hypothesis $\int |g_n| + |g| dm \to \int 2|g| dm$, moreover $|g-g_n| \to 0 $ a.e, thus by a generalized version of the dominated convergence theorem we conclude that 
$$
\|g_n - g \| \to 0
$$

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your reasoning is fine, except that you may want to add some more detail as to how
$$\left|\, \int_{X} g_n \, dm - \int_{X}g\, dm \,\right|$$
is related to the (absolute value of) the difference of the norms.  Specifically, I’d write something like
$$\left|\, ||g_n||_{1} - ||g||_1 \,\right| = \left|\, \int_{X} |g_n| \, dm - \int_{X} |g| \, dm \,\right| \leq \int_{X} \left| \,|g_n| - |g| \,\right| \, dm \leq \int_{X} |g_n - g| \, dm.$$

The converse is false.  As a counterexample, let $X = [0, 1]$ with Lebesgue measure.
Let $g_n = 2 \, \chi_{[0,1/2]}$ (two times the characteristic function of $[0, 1/2]$) if $n$ is even, and let $g_n = 2\chi_{[1/2, 1]}$ if $n$ is odd.  Finally, let $g(x) = 1$ for all $x \in [0,1]$.