# Convergence of sequence of function in norm.

Tags: normed-spaces, lp-spaces

> Let $1\leq p<\infty$. Suppose that $\{f_k\}$ is a sequence in $L^p(X,\mathcal{M},\mu)$ such that the limit
>
> $f(x)=\lim_{k \to \infty}f_k(x)$
>
> exists for $\mu$-a.e. $x\in X$. Asumme that
>
> $\liminf_{k \to \infty} \|f_k \|_p=a$ is finite. Then prove that
>
> a) $f \in L^P$
>
> b) $\|f \|_p\leq a$
>
> c) Assuming that $\|f \|_p=\lim_{k\to \infty}\|f_k \|_p$,
>
> $\lim_{k\to \infty} \|f-f_k\|_p=0$

By Fatous' Lemma, I proved b). Is the fact that $f(x)=\lim_{k \to \infty}f_k(x)$ exists $\mu$-a.e. guarantees a)?.

For c), using inequality $(a+b)^p \leq 2^{p-1}(a^p+b^p)$, I hope

$|f-f_k|^p \leq 2^{p-1}(|f|^p+|f_k|^p)$ hold. Then I can use dominated convergence theorem. But with $f\in L^p$, I don't know how to proceed.

Any help will be thankful.

Comment: Part c) Posible duplicate http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1314902/convergence-in-lp-spaces

Comment: @SW is $(X,\mathcal{M},\mu)$ a complete measure space? That guarantees $f$ is measurable. Since $\|f\|_p$ is finite as well, you may deduce from these two facts that $f \in L^p$.

Comment: Well, no, $\mu$ can be any measure. This textbook uses $\mu$ as arbitrary measure. Maybe I should use b) first.

Comment: But you need $f$ to be measurable as well. So how do you know $f$ is measurable?

Comment: Combining the existence of $\lim_{k\to \infty}f_k(x)$ and Fatous' Lemma for $\liminf_{k\to \infty} \|f_k\|<\infty$, b) seems true.

Comment: The existence of $\lim_{k\to \infty} f_k(x)$ only holds $\mu$-a.e., not everywhere. The condition $\liminf_{k\to \infty} \|f_k\|_p < \infty$ has nothing to do with the measurability of $f$.

Answer (score 1):

For c), apply Fatou's lemma to $2^{p-1}(|f|^p + |f_k|^p) - |f - f_k|^p$, giving

$$\liminf_{k \to \infty} \int_X 2^{p-1}(|f|^p + |f_k|^p - |f - f_k|^p)\, d\mu\ge 2^p \int_X |f|^p\, d\mu.$$

Thus

$$2^{p-1}(\|f\|_p^p + \liminf_{k\to \infty} \|f_k\|_p^p) - \limsup_{k\to \infty} \|f - f_k\|_p^p \ge 2^p\|f\|_p^p.$$

Since $\|f_k\|_p^p \to \|f\|_p^p$, we have

$$2^p\|f\|_p^p - \limsup_{k\to \infty} \|f - f_k\|_p^p \ge 2^p \|f\|_p^p.$$

As $\|f\|_p^p < \infty$, we deduce

$$0\ge \limsup_{k\to \infty} \|f - f_k\|_p^p .$$

Hence $\|f - f_k\|_p \to 0$.